# Limit IP connection for specific port in forward traffic

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, port-forwarding

I have a server on which I have done port forwarding. This means that each user connects to the server with a dedicated port and the traffic sent by the user is directed to the remote server. I used the following command to do the forward port and it works well

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8090 -j DNAT --to-destination remote_ip:8090`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`
To further monitor and control traffic consumption on my server, I want to set a limit for each port. That is, each user connects to the server with 2 IPs. If there is more than 2 IPs, the user will be disconnected. I do this to prevent abuse. I try these codes :

`iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn --dport 8090 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 2 -j DROP`

Then I connected to the server with two different IPs at the same time, i was expecting the IP limit to work and one of my connections to be disconnected but both IPs were connected and this command did not work. Is it possible to set the IP limit for forwarding trafic in iptables?

Answer (score 0):

2 is not above 2.

You specified `--connlimit-above 2`. That means it matches on the *third* connection.

Comment: I put it on `--connlimit-above 1` but it didn't work. Are the rest of the code correct?

Comment: Did you try to set `connlimit` to `remote_ip:8090`? Somehow when routing is enabled, `connlimit` works only for destination addresses.